# when i use conn.getresponse(),there are some error

Tags: python

```
import sys
import pdb
import http.client


def PassParse():


    headers = {"Accept":" application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Authorization":" Basic YWRtaW46YXNkZg==",
    "Referer":" http://192.168.1.113:8080/#/apps",
    "Accept-Language":" zh-CN",
        "Accept-Encoding":" gzip, deflate",
    "User-Agent":" Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko LBBROWSER",
    "Host":" 192.168.1.113:8080",
    "DNT":" 1",
    "Connection":" Keep-Alive"};      
    conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("192.168.1.113:8080");     

    conn.request(method="Get",url="/api/v1/login",body=None,headers=headers);     

    response = conn.getresponse();
    responseText = response.getheaders("content-lentgh");
    print ("succ!^_^!");
    #print (response.status);
    print (responseText);  
    conn.close();  


run error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python\test1-3.4.py", line 32, in <module>
    PassParse();
  File "F:\Python\test1-3.4.py", line 24, in PassParse
    response = conn.getresponse();
  File "E:\program files\Python 3.4.3\lib\http\client.py", line 1171, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "E:\program files\Python 3.4.3\lib\http\client.py", line 351, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "E:\program files\Python 3.4.3\lib\http\client.py", line 333, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
http.client.BadStatusLine: <html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the problem using the following code:

from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

res=requests.get('http://192.168.1.113:8080/api/v1/login', auth=(username, password));

Answer (score 0):

From the Python docs for `httplib`:

```
exception httplib.BadStatusLine
A subclass of HTTPException. Raised if a server responds with a HTTP status code that we don’t understand.
```

Sounds like your API might not be returning something that can be parsed as a valid HTTP response with a valid HTTP status code. You might want to check that the code for your API endpoint is working as expected and is not failing.

Besides that, your code runs fine except for one thing: `response.getheader()` takes an argument, while `response.getheaders()` takes no argument, so Python with complain about that once you resolve the `BadStatusLine` exception.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the httpserver didn't return valid http response, you can use telnet to check it.

```
telnet 192.168.1.113 8080
```

then send:

```
GET /api/v1/login HTTP/1.1
```

reference: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html